# Custom HTML CSS Class

Tags: html, css

Maybe i am doing this wrong but i have:

```
<td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: text-top; background:#666;">
<strong><div style="color:#FFF;">Description:</div></strong>
</td>
```

Is it possible to create a css `<style>` class, only one so i can do something like:

```
<td class="darkstyle">Description</td>
```

And the `<div>` would get applied as well or would it need to be:

```
<td class="darkstyle"><div>Description</div></td>
```

My problem with the class is that i can change the background or the foreground but not both and not for nested elements. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

```
    .darkstyle
    {
        background: #666;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    <td colspan="4" class="darkstyle">
        <div>Description</div>
    </td>
```

Maybe i did it wrong, the background changes color but not the text color of the `Description`, this stays black :S

Comment: You can select multiple things and apply the same style to them, e.g. `td, div { background: #666; }`. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: you should be able to change the background and foreground color. They are not mutually exclusive. You should be able to do `.darkstyle {width: 15%; vertical-align: text-top; background:#666;color:#FFF;}`

Comment: and the only html you need is `<td class="darkstyle">Description</td>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors  ]||[ 

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp ]||[ 

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 ]||[ 

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/ ]||[

Comment: @Andrew what if the field is going to have code, html, special characters and other things. What would be best to use? `<p>`, `<div>`, `<spam>`, `<td>`, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this ?

```
.darkstyle{
   width: 15%; 
   vertical-align: text-top; 
   background:#666;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

you can also access to the div like this :

```
.darkstyle{
   width: 15%; 
   vertical-align: text-top; 
   background:#666;
}

.darkstyle div{
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Not sure to understand, your question :p

Comment: I am stupid haha, i already had the same thing as you. The reason it wasn't working is because i had the wrong path in my java executable, so the .html was never being updated. *Smacks my head against the table*, i was going crazy wondering why this wasn't working :S

Answer (score 0):

So this question has to do with CSS specificity and inheritance. You can read more here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

But the general gist as follows (from the link above):

1. Inline styles (Presence of style in document).
   An inline style lives within your XHTML document. It is attached directly to the element to be styled. E.g. `<h1 style="color: #fff;">`
2. IDs (# of ID selectors) ID is an identifier for your page elements, such as `#div.`
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes (# of class selectors).
   This group includes `.classes, [attributes]` and pseudo-classes such as `:hover, :focus` etc.
4. Elements and pseudo-elements (# of Element (type) selectors). Including for instance `:before` and `:after`.